# How can i add a Gaussian, salt pepper and skettle noise for an image of 256X256 using sliding window of length 8X8

Tags: matlab

I have looked in to your forum for many clarifications and hope I get this also clarified.
My issue is about writing a code to add a Gaussian/speckle/salt pepper noise to an image and calculate a MSE and Quality Index of it. I want to create this using a sliding window technique.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you want to do this using a sliding window?

An easy way to add noise to an image in Matlab is the imnoise function (if you have the Image Processing Toolbox).

```
im = rgb2gray(imread('http://www.actiondonation.org/images/donate_a_sailboat.jpg'));
figure(1);
imagesc(im);
figure(2);
imagesc(imnoise(im, 'gaussian'));
figure(3);
imagesc(imnoise(im, 'salt & pepper', 0.1));
```